# Extract specific array in rails from API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm hooked up with an API, and I want to show all the profiles the user has. However I only want to show the profiles where 'service' is equal to 'test'.

Currently I'm doing:

```
<%= debug @client.profiles %>
```

which, quite obviously shows all the profiles of the client. However I want to only show the profiles where the profiles, service is equal to test.

Does anybody know how to do that? In an ideal situation I create a loop, like so:

```
@client.profiles.each do |profile|
```

and it only loops through the profiles, that I want.

Comment: What are `service` and `test`? Are they `attributes` of `Client`?

Comment: @pavan service is an attribute of profiles. Where test is the value that service has.

Comment: Is `profiles` a relation or a method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where` clause for finding profiles where 'service' is equal to 'test'.

```
@client.profiles.where(service: "test")
```

Then you can loop with the same for profile.

Comment: Sachin where doesn't work. I made the mistake to think it was a hash, it's actually an array.

Comment: Client has_many profiles, and you want profile which service value should be 'test', right?

Comment: Yes. If I do what you suggested I get 'undefined value where'

Comment: Have you setup relationship in model ? For client model set has_many :profiles and for profile model set belongs_to :client

Comment: I think you are not getting proper value for @client, For debug check in rails console `Client.first.profiles.where(service: "test")`. If its work then you are not getting proper @client

Comment: take a look at this: https://bufferapp.com/developers/api/profiles#schedules

when I do @client.profiles it prints out all my profiles perfectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70994/discussion-between-sja-and-sachin-gevariya).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

In client model

```
  class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :profiles, -> { where(service: "test") }
  end
```

In Profile model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord:::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

In `profiles` table must contain `client_id`

In Controller

```
 class Clients < ApplicationController
    def show
      @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
```

IN`/app/views/clients/show.html.erb`
`

```
<%  @client.profiles.each do |profile| %>

 <%= profile.name %>
<%end %>
```